# String length after kleen's closure in finite-autometa theory

Tags: finite-automata, kleene-star

**Note: Not sure if this is the correct site for this question. I found other finite-autometa theory questions here, so posting here.**

Suppose a language is defined over two letters

```
L1 = { aa , b }
```

We take Kleen closure over it:

```
S1 = aab
S2 = aaaabb
```

Now my question is simple, what is the string length of these two strings S1 and S2?

According to my understanding since string length can only be determined by the number of character it uses and since 'aa' is a single character so string lengths for both strings should be:

```
S1 = 2 characters or string of length 2
S2 = 4 characters or string of length 4
```

According to my teacher string length for each string is

```
S1 = 3 characters
S2 = 6 characters
```

Comment: Generally, a character is not a string. A language is a set of strings, not characters, so when you define `L1 = { aa, b }` this is the language of strings `aa` and `b`. The string `aa` is the character `a` repeated. The string `b` is the character `b` once. The Kleene closure of a language operations on the strings of that language, not its alphabet. It sounds like your teacher is muddling terminology if they are calling `aa` a character/letter. It's a string, not a letter. With this interpretation, `S1` is 3 characters, and `S2` is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two different concepts: languages/strings and alphabets/symbols.

Languages are sets of strings. Alphabets are (nonempty finite) sets of symbols. Strings are (typically finite) sequences of symbols.

You say L1 is defined over two letters, but then write L1 = {aa, b}. So you could mean two things:

1. L1 is a set of strings over the alphabet {aa, b} where aa and b are understood to be symbols.
2. L1 is a language of two strings aa and b, where a and b are understood to be symbols of an implied alphabet.

Under the first interpretation, S1 and S2 have lengths 2 and 4 characters, respectively. Under the second interpretation, S1 and S2 have lengths 3 and 6 characters, respectively. Crucially, the meaning of * (Kleene star) is overloaded:

1. E*, where E is an alphabet, is the set of all strings over the symbols in the alphabet.
2. L*, where L is a language, is the set of all strings formed by concatenating strings in L with each other.

Often, when it does not cause confusion, alphabets can be treated as being essentially the same as (finite, nonempty) languages of strings of length one.

HOWEVER, they are not the same thing, and dropping that distinction has confused you (and lots of other people)… so it may be a simplification of dubious value.

Comment: My teacher told me the first assumption, that { aa, b } are two symbols and not strings. So from that I concluded that length will be 2 and 4 characters and not 3 and 6.

Answer (score 1):

**The length of a string is the number of characters in the string including spaces.**
For example:

length of "cat" is 3

length of "" is 0

length of "cat " is 4

**Notice that spaces count in the length, but the double quotes do not.**

In this case "aa" is considered 1 character instead of 2.

S2 is 4 characters long as "aa" is considered 1 character

For more details you can refer to this link:

```
https://bilalamjad.net/automata-alphabets-and-strings/
```